# How to create gutenberg block using REST API independently or as headless way?

Tags: plugins, rest-api, block-editor

I want to create page/post using REST API but I don't know how to create it in WordPress using REST API independently or as headless way.

I want to create this page with new Gutenberg blocks. So I also don't know how we can attach multiple Gutenberg blocks with one page and build this page the same way like we create it in the WordPress admin panel because when we trying to create page/post using REST API then in admin panel it will show only one block called "classic"

Can anyone help me how can I pass data in REST API so it will create multiple block and as per our requirement?

Answer (score 5):

Block editor blocks are dynamically constructed by parsing the HTML of `post_content`. Blocks are delimited by HTML comments that looks like these:

```
<!-- wp:image -->
<figure class="wp-block-image"><img src="source.jpg" alt="" /></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->
```

The way the actual data of blocks is stored depends *entirely* on the block. Blocks can either store their attributes inside the HTML comment as JSON (the editor takes care of this), like this example from [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/principles/key-concepts/#blocks):

```
<!-- wp:latest-posts {"postsToShow":4,"displayPostDate":true} /-->
```

Or they can reconstruct the attributes by parsing the saved HTML. It could even be a mix. For example, the Button block stores the `className` attribute as in the comment as JSON, but recovers the link and label by parsing the HTML:

```
<!-- wp:button {"className":"is-style-outline"} -->
<div class="wp-block-button is-style-outline"><a class="wp-block-button__link" href="https://wpthemetestdata.wordpress.com/2018/11/03/block-button/">another button</a></div>
<!-- /wp:button -->
```

The possible ways of storing block data are documented [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-attributes/), and every block will work differently.

The problem here is that Blocks are not designed to be hand-written. They're supposed to be created with the Block Editor. The logic used to convert the HTML in `post_content` back into a block in the Block Editor only exists in the code for that block. So to write HTML that can be converted into a block, you need to study the code used to register that block, to see what format it expects.

If you have a non-WordPress application that needs to create block content, the only *reliable* approach would be to adapt the block editor to that application.